# Accessibility for jQuery selectric plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectric

i'm making my web page accessible for people with disabilities and the main issue with jQuery plugin for select. How can i seе labels for screen readers while using keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is way too broad to be answered. You can substitute selectors with lists that can be accessed with `TAB` or similar.